# Regular Expression Lookahead with optional piece of URL

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm having problems writing an all encompassing regular expression for the following.

I have a url in the format

> www.someurl.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/page?bunchofrandomvariables

I also have a slightly modified version of this URL going

> www.someurl.com/dir1/newdirectory/dir2/dir3/page?bunchofrandomvariables

Where newdirectory can be alphanumeric and can include dashes.

I want a regular expresssion that can match on the original URL (with no "newdirectory") AND any "newdirectory" that comes to pass.

My first attempt was something akin to

```
^www.someurl.com/dir1/[a-zA-Z]+/dir2/dir3/page?.*
```

Unfortunately, that breaks the 1st example, since the [a-zA-Z]+ captures "dir2".  Is there anyway to write this with lookaheads to capture both examples in one line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just modified your regex:

- Escaped the slaches (maybe it's not required depending of the language you're using)
- made the `/newdirectory` part optional using `?`

  ```
  ^www.someurl.com\/dir1(\/[a-zA-Z]+)?\/dir2\/dir3\/page?.*
  ```

[`Working DEMO`](http://regex101.com/r/aI4fE0)

Comment: Yep, it was as simple as that.  I had tried something similar earlier in the thought process, but I hadn't thought to put the "/" after dir1 inside the ()?.

Thanks a million for the help